# WPF - Shut-off autogen of Main in App.g.cs

Tags: wpf, app.xaml

I'm learning WPF.

I want to provide my own Main method in my App.xaml.cs rather than getting one generated for me in App.g.cs. However I keep getting conflicts because I haven't found out how to stop an additional Main from being generated.

Is there a setting in my project file or elsewhere that controls this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the answer here. http://learnwpf.com/post/2007/12/13/How-can-I-provide-my-own-Main%28%29-method-in-my-WPF-application.aspx

It is:

> The way WPF knows to create the Main() method for a particular xaml file is through the build action property set for App.xaml - it has a build action of ApplicationDefinition. By changing this to Page WPF won't create the Main method and you can provide your own in a regular class file you add to the project.

However in the comments to the above blog, a comment notes there may be issues with blend and it references: http://blogs.msdn.com/expression/archive/2008/04/09/creating-a-wpf-blend-project-that-loads-resources-in-code.aspx .  I don't fully understand the issues yet.

Answer (score 7):

You can also just create a separate class (for example, `Entry`) which is responsible for bootstrapping your application. Then go to project settings and set your startup object to `Entry`. That way you don't even have to disable the autogenerated method.

Comment: Seems like the cleanest way to do this, are there any drawbacks I wonder?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to set the Build Action in the Properties window from ApplicationDefinition to Page for App.Xaml.

Then you can define your own entry point.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to forgo defining an Application-derived class in XAML, so you can manually define the Main method with your custom requirement

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

1. Copy the data from your app.xaml file
2. Delete app.xaml file and re-create with the same name
3. Create `main` method in .cs file, and paste your old copied code into it

Answer (score 0):

The Easy way just create a class like Startup.cs with build action to compile 
and remove ApplicationDefinition from App.xaml convert that to page
and remove it from any other file in the application