# Can't find resource Locator when creating window in App.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am creating my main window inside the `App.xaml.cs` constructor like this:

```
MainWindow wnd = new MainWindow();

Application.Current.MainWindow = wnd;
wnd.Show();
```

Starting the application gives me a `XamlParseException`, the resource with the name "Locator" cannot be found.

This is the suspicious line:

```
<DockPanel x:Name="MainPanel"  DataContext="{Binding MainWindowViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" LastChildFill="True">
```

Using `StartupUri` in App.xaml works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you have your `Locator` resource in the App.xaml. The reason why it does not work when you put your code in the constructor is because App.xaml is not loaded yet. If you see the default `Main` method generated by visual studio, you can see that `App.InitializeComponent` is called after the constructor. The resources in the `xaml` file are initialized at this point.

You can fix the issue by putting your code in the [Application.Startup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup(v=vs.110).aspx) event which Occurs when the Run method of the Application object is called. (If `StartupUri` is set, it's also initialized after `Run` is called.)

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    var window = new MainWindow();
    window.Show();
}
```

Of course you can subscribe to that event and write the code in an event hander. However, when we want to subscribe to events in a base class, it's better to override the `OnXXX` method for the corresponding event.

On and btw, you don't need this line `Application.Current.MainWindow = wnd;`. It will be done automatically for you by wpf.

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm. What If I don't want the GUI to show up at all?! Creating no window does not really help, since the app is still running without a window. I want to implement a /noGui parameter, if it's set, no window will be created and some task get's done. Calling Application.Current.Shutdown() seems to be wrong to me.

Comment: In that case, you need to modify App.g.cs. There you can find the Main method. You can add your logic here. If the parameter is set, don't run the app. Else do.

Comment: Application.Current.Shutdown() will not work because it makes App.Run() return which means the program will end if you don't have custom logic set at Main

Comment: Application.Current.Shutdown() seems to work, the program closes. And the App.g.cs is inside the obj folder. I guess this is a more correct approach, when altering the App.g.cs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052868/wpf-shut-off-autogen-of-main-in-app-g-cs . Guess I will stick to Shutdown() for now, seems to be working well. Start => Check console param => do stuff => Shutdown()